# How can I create an Android action-bar that works with both Dark and Light theme?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I've got an action bar built following some docs and tutorials found on a google search, but it doesn't style correctly on KitKat. Any pointers / guides that are sure to work correctly on KitKat, and looking good for both Dark and Light theme?

Answer (score 1):

I just so happens that I've been solving a very similar issue myself. If you decide to wirte the style yourself, there is a greater chance of error. I would recommend using this tool to design your action bar

http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

It generates all necessary 9-patch sources and xml files, all you have to do is download the archived bundle and include them in your project. Don't forget to update the theme in your manifest.